# Pytest fails on importing pyhive

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on writing some data tests. Super simple nothing crazy.

Here is what my current directory looks like.

```
.
├── README.md
├── hive_tests
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── schema_checks_hive.py
│   ├── test_schema_checks_hive.py
│   └── yaml
│       └── job_output.address_stats.yaml
└── postgres
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── schema_checks_pg.py
    ├── test_schema_checks_pg.py
    └── yaml
```

When I `cd` in to postgres and run `pytest` all my tests pass.

When I `cd` in to hive_test and run `pytest` I am getting an import error.

Here is my `schema_checks_hive.py` file.

```
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, sys
import yaml

def check_column_name_hive(schema, table):
    query = "DESCRIBE {0}.{1}".format(schema, table)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    print(df.columns)
    return df.columns

check_column_name_hive('myschema', 'mytable')
```

Here is my `test_schema_checks_hive.py` file where the tests are located.

```
import schema_checks_hive as sch
import pandas as pd
import yaml
import sys, os


def test_column_names_hive():
      for filename in os.listdir('yaml'):
        data = ""
        with open("yaml/{0}".format(filename), 'r') as stream:
            data = yaml.safe_load(stream)

        schema = data['schema']
        table = data['table']
        cols = data['columns']
        df = sch.check_column_name_hive(schema, table)

        assert len(cols) == len(df)
        assert cols == df.tolist()
```

When I run `Pytest` I get an error that says:

```
mportError while importing test module '/Usersdata/
tests/hive_tests/test_schema_checks_hive.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_schema_checks_hive.py:1: in <module>
    import schema_checks_hive as sch
schema_checks_hive.py:1: in <module>
    from pyhive import hive
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyhive
```

I would love any help! Thanks so much.

Comment: Make sure that `pytest` is run with the same Python where you installed `pyhive`.

Comment: @Sanyash can you explain that further.

Comment: when you run `pytest` it shows you the Python interpreter that is used for this run. If you have several interpreters, it can be run with other than that you installed `pyhive` to. After running `pytest` you can see the line `platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0`, it shows that Python3.6.6 interpreter is used.

Comment: @Sanyash . this is what I am seeing.  `platform darwin -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0`

Comment: Check if you installed `pyhive` in this Python3.7.1, not in some other.

Comment: @Sanyash . I ran `pip list` and I have it installed

Comment: What does `pip --version` output?